# How to efficiently iterate over a large pandas DataFrame and update values based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas DataFrame with millions of rows and multiple columns. I need to iterate over the DataFrame and update certain values based on multiple conditions. However, the traditional methods like using iterrows() or apply() are quite slow and inefficient for this large dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

# Assume 'df' is a large DataFrame with columns 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D'

# Iterate over the DataFrame and update values based on conditions
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A'] > 10 and row['B'] == 'SomeValue':
        df.at[index, 'C'] = row['A'] * 2
    elif row['B'] == 'OtherValue':
        df.at[index, 'D'] = row['C'] + row['D']
    else:
        df.at[index, 'C'] = row['A'] + row['B']
```

Comment: You can do e.g. `df[df.A > 10 & df.B == "SomeValue", "C"] = df[df.A > 10 & df.B == "SomeValue", "A"] * 2` instead.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with large DataFrames, iterating over rows using `iterrows()` or using `apply()` can indeed be slow and inefficient. However, you can optimize your code by using vectorized operations provided by pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Assume 'df' is a large DataFrame with columns 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D'

# Apply conditions and update values using numpy.where()
df['C'] = np.where((df['A'] > 10) & (df['B'] == 'SomeValue'), df['A'] * 2,
                   np.where(df['B'] == 'OtherValue', df['C'], df['A'] + df['B']))

df['D'] = np.where(df['B'] == 'OtherValue', df['C'] + df['D'], df['D'])
```